# Send multiple files by email and also add a body message to the email (Unix Korn Shell)

Tags: shell, file, email, unix, mailx

I'm trying to send multiple files by email but also include a body message in the email, I've tried couple of ways with no luck, the following code is for send multiple files:

`(uuencode file1.txt file1.txt ; uuencode file2.txt file2.txt) | mailx -s "test" email@test.com`

I've tried this option with no luck:

`echo "This is the body message" | (uuencode file1.txt file1.txt ; uuencode file2.txt file2.txt) | mailx -s "test" email@test.com`

any idea how could be the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(echo "This is the body message"; uuencode file1.txt file1.txt; uuencode file2.txt file2.txt) | mailx -s "test" email@test.com
```

The issue with your command is that you are piping the output of `echo` into the subshell and it is getting ignored as `uuencode` isn't reading from stdin.

You can use `{ ... }` to avoid the subshell:

```
{ echo "This is the body message"; uuencode file1.txt file1.txt; uuencode file2.txt file2.txt; } | mailx -s "test" email@test.com
```

If you are doing this in a script and you want it to look more readable, then:

```
{
  echo "This is the body message"
  uuencode file1.txt file1.txt
  uuencode file2.txt file2.txt
} | mailx -s "test" email@test.com
```